# Where to define helper functions in React?

Tags: reactjs, function, single-page-application

I keep stumbling upon code duplication of basic helper functions like the following:

```js
function percentageWithCommas(x?) {
    try {
        return (x * 100).toLocaleString("en-UK", { maximumFractionDigits: 1 }) + '%';
    } catch (e) {
        return (x * 100).toFixed(2) + '%';
    }
}
```

This specific function I found in many TSX-files within different folders, e.g. in `myView1/components/fileA.tsx`, `myView2/components/fileB.tsx`, `myView2/components/fileC.tsx`.

How can I quickly refactor that, such that I only have to maintain and change code at *one* place? I feel like there was a reason that my predecessors did not write a component for that.

Comment: I often create a utils directory and put all my various functional utilities there with a common export index file.

Comment: @DrewReese  tobiasfried's answer is what I needed. The only thing which puzzles me is possible reasons for such a design, why somebody would implement that like this in first place. Is there any possible scenario, where code-duplication makes sense?

Comment: @tobiasfried - thanks for your cheer-up. As I said, I really invested time to investigate that helper function issue, and is really hard to debug somebody else's code which does not have any kind of documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a utils module, add a file an stick this stuff in there. Then import the module or the functions you want from it wherever needed.

**src/utils/index.js**

```js
export function percentageWithCommas(x?) {
    try {
        return (x * 100).toLocaleString("en-UK", { maximumFractionDigits: 1 }) + '%';
    } catch (e) {
        return (x * 100).toFixed(2) + '%';
    }
}
```

**src/components/ComponentA.js**

```js
import { percentageWithCommas } from '../utils';

export default ComponentA = props => {
    const formattedPercent = percentageWithCommas(0.05);    // '5%'
    ...
}
```